# Using Angular Material autocomplete displayFn asynchronously

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

How can I return an `Observable<string>` from Angular Material autocomplete [`displayFn`](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) ? It seems to only support returning a `string`. Problem: my display value needs to be translated, and the translation service only returns an `Observable<string>`.

Comment: Do you have a [Minimal Workable StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) that replicates the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4863